# created element with ajax ,not act autocomplete

Tags: forms, ajax

i have a select option value , in change create a text field with auto complete feature,
every thing is ok , but autocomplelete of this element not work!!!

part of my code

```
        $form['azlocation']=array(
            '#type' => 'select',
            '#title' => 'location',
            '#options' => array(1,2,3),
            '#default_value' => 1,
            '#description' => t('select your news location.'),
            '#ajax' => array(
                    'event' => 'change',
                    'callback' => 'country_select_f',
                    //'path' =>'roadtonowhere',
                    'wrapper' => 'city-term',
                    'method' => 'replace',
                    'effect' => 'fade',
            ),
            );
    $form['field_terms_city']= array(
            '#markup' => '<div id="city-term"></div>');



    function country_select_f(&$form, $form_state){
$form['city_list_item2'] =array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('select city (optional)'),
        '#autocomplete_path' => 'user/autocomplete',
        '#weight' => -1,
        '#attributes' => array('id' =>'city-term-select'),
);
```

where is the problem?

Comment: tnx. for your reply. but before i test this i myself found solution. tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done it by this:

```
$form['azlocation']=array(
            '#type' => 'select',
            '#title' => 'location',
            '#options' => $tags,
            '#default_value' => 1,
            '#description' => t('select your news location.'),
            '#ajax' => array(
                    'event' => 'change',
                    'callback' => 'country_select_f',
                    //'path' =>'roadtonowhere',
                    'wrapper' => 'city-term',
                    'method' => 'replace',
                    'effect' => 'fade',
            ),
            );

    $form['field_terms_city']= array(
            '#markup' => '<div id="city-term"></div>');

function country_select_f(&$form, $form_state){

$form['city_list_item'] =array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('select city (optional)'),
        //'#autocomplete_path' => 'user/autocomplete',
        '#autocomplete_path' => "events/autocomplete/".$form_state['triggering_element']['#value'],
        //'#autocomplete_path' => "events/autocomplete/".$form_state['triggering_element']['#value'],
        '#weight' => -1,
        '#attributes' => array('id' =>'city-term-select'),
);
return ('<div id="city-term">'.drupal_render($form['city_list_item']).'</div>');
}
```

My trick was to use:

```
return ('<div id="city-term">'.drupal_render($form['city_list_item']).'</div>');
```

I hope this be useful in the future for users with similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$form['azlocation'] = array( 
'#type' => 'select',
'#title' => 'location',
'#options' => array(1, 2, 3),
'#default_value' => 1,
'#description' => t('select your news location.'),
'#ajax' => array(
  'event' => 'change',
  'callback' => 'country_select_f',
  //'path' =>'roadtonowhere',
  'wrapper' => 'city-term',
  'method' => 'replace',
  'effect' => 'fade',
 ),
 );
 $form['field_terms_city'] = array(
 '#type' => 'textfield',
 '#title' => t('select city (optional)'),
 '#prefix' => '<div id="city-term">',
 '#suffix' => '</div>',
 );
 return $form;
}
function country_select_f($form, $form_state){
   $form['field_terms_city']['#autocomplete_path'] = 'user/autocomplete';
   return $form['field_terms_city'];
}
```